# Python 3.6 Bitwise operations on byte datatype (>>, <<, |, & ) throws error:

Tags: python, python-3.6, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I am a beginner and I am trying to perform bit wise operations on an element from 'byte' array

Example code:

```
step1_result[i] = (bytes((seedrandom[i] >> 3)) | bytes((seedrandom[i] << 5)))
```

```
>>> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'bytes' and 'bytes'
```

`step1_result` and `seedrandom` is a list with 'byte' type elements

Is there a specific method to apply bitwise operations on a byte in Python?

Comment: Show the offending line, please, your code does not use `>>`.`bytes` can be thought of as a list of characters, so shifting that by other `bytes` is undefined.

Comment: Code has been updated

Comment: There still is no `>>` with two `bytes` as operands in that code.

Answer (score 4):

Python's bitwise operators [only operate on integers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types), so you need to convert each `byte` to an `int` before performing a bitwise operation.

```
import sys
b1, b2 = [b'\x77', b'\x88']
int.from_bytes(b1, sys.byteorder) << int.from_bytes(b2, sys.byteorder)
```

Note that explicit conversion is not necessary if your bytes are in an actual [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray), because indexing on a bytearray returns ints.

```
ba = bytearray(b'\x77\x01')
ba[0] << ba[1]
```

Likewise if the bytes are in a composite [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) object

```
bs = b'\x77\x01'
bs[0] << bs[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

`bytes` is an immutable sequence type, not a numeric type. Did you mean an elementwise operation, such as `bytes(map(lambda x: (x<<3) & 0xff, b'\xff\x03'))` (list comprehension form: `bytes([(x<<3) & 0xff for x in b'\xff\x03'])`)? Note that bytes can't exceed 255, so I needed to mask to 8 bits before collecting it in a second bytes object. Python doesn't have a standard type for a singular byte, just as it doesn't have one for a singular character. If you read a single element from a `bytes` object that byte is converted into an `int`.

Comment: I want to do bitwise operations and i want the operations on '8 bits' bytes. Since, by default size is taken as 128bits, output is not coming as expected.

Comment: Where did you get 128 from? Python supports arbitrarily large integers.